# How to set back-end language per user?

Tags: plugins, admin, multi-language, user-interface

I would like to use the english interface for the back-end but I would like to set it to native language for an editor. I know WPML has this feature, but I don't want to install the unsupported WPML just for this reason.

What I am looking is a tiny plugin which gives a switchbox for the user profile page for setting the back-end language. Is there such a plugin?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you seen
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-native-dashboard/?

I think it does exactly what you are asking.

Also 'interesting' is http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/in-their-language/ which attempts to set the locale automatically based n browser settings.

Comment: WP Native Dashboard is GREAT! Just what I was looking for. Has 4 ways of setting language!

Answer (score 2):

Starting with Wordpress 4.1 (maybe even earlier, I don't know) this functionality is built-in (no need for a plugin). Simply:

1. Download the language pack of your choice from http://wpcentral.io/internationalization/
2. extract the content into `wp-content/languages` (create the `languages` folder if it does not exist yet)
3. Done!

Logon as the editor who needs a different language, and go to his/her profile and set the *Admin Language*.

Comment: I think this might only be for wp.com, not self-hosted?  As evinced by [this post](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/user-selectable-admin-interface-language) and the fact that there are [plugins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-language-per-user/) ([2](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-native-dashboard/)) for it

Comment: This is indeed now native, but I think the version introduced was 4.7 ( see https://wptavern.com/wordpress-4-7-to-introduce-user-specific-language-setting-for-the-admin )

Answer (score 0):

The plugin that you need is "Admin Language Per User".

1. Download the language pack of your choice from http://wpcentral.io/internationalization/
2. Extract the content into wp-content/languages (create the languages folder if it does not exist yet)
3. Install and activate this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-language-per-user/ (Compatible up to: 4.5.2)
4. Login as admin user, go to your profile page (http://www.yoursite.com/wp-admin/profile.php), change the "Site language" field.

In this way you are changing just the language of the backoffice for your user.