# Different back-end language for different users?

Tags: users, multi-language, language

I've been searching the internet for the last hour but I can't find anything up-to-date to do this (all the suggestions are about plugins that haven't been updated in ages, see [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28975/how-to-set-back-end-language-per-user?rq=1)).

Is there any way to specify a different **back-end** language for different users? I like my WP back-end to be in English but all my coworkers prefer it in their own language (Italian), is there any way to live in peace with them?

Props if your method doesn't rely on URLs (/?lang=it and such) and isn't a plugin, but a functions.php function.

Thanks, have a great new year!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We could try to filter the <strike>`WPLANG` option</strike> *locale*  [(see e.g. this approach from the related list here on the right](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53326/change-admin-language-based-on-user-in-single-site)  by @brasofilo, that's based on [this one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/52436/26350) by @toscho ):

```
/**
 * Override locale settings for the current (non-admin) user
 */
is_admin() && add_filter( 'locale', function( $locale )
{
    // Modify locale for non-admins (we don't want to override this on the settings pages)
    if( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )
    {
        // Get admin language for the current user
        $lang = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'wpse_lang', true );

        // Use 'en_US' as default
        $locale = ! empty( $lang ) ? sanitize_text_field( $lang ) : 'en_US';
    }   
    return $locale; 
} );
```

where we check if the current user has the `wpse_lang` user meta key set, with values like `is_IS`, `da_DK`, ...

Then we could add the language selection for each user, on the user settings page.

There we could use the [`wp_dropdown_languages()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_languages) function, with the [`get_available_languages()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_available_languages/) function, to display the select-box for available languages.

Here's an [example](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/6711/26350) by @sanchothefat on how we can add custom user settings.

We can display the user language selection with:

```
/**
 * Display available language dropdown
 */
function wpse_user_language( $user ) 
{
    // Only display for non-admins, but allow admins to edit for other users
    if( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) && $user->ID == get_current_user_id() )
        return;

    // Get the current 'wp_lang' settings
    $lang = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'wpse_lang', true ); 
    ?>
    <table class="form-table">
        <tr id="wpse-lang-selection">
            <th scope="row">
               <label for="wpse_lang">
                   <?php _e( 'WPSE' ); ?> - <?php _e( 'Site Language' ); ?>
               </label>
            </th>
            <td><?php wp_dropdown_languages( 
                    [
                        'id'                          => 'wpse_lang',
                        'name'                        => 'wpse_lang',
                        'languages'                   => get_available_languages(),
                        'translations'                => [],
                        'selected'                    => $lang,
                        'show_available_translations' => false,
                    ] 
                );
            ?></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'wpse_user_language' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'wpse_user_language' );
```

Note that here we re-use the *Site Language* string, because it's translated.

The update part is:

```
/**
 * Update the 'wp_lang' user settings
 */    
function wpse_user_language_save( $user_id ) 
{
    if( current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) && isset( $_POST['wpse_lang'] ) )
        return update_user_meta( $user_id, 'wpse_lang', $_POST['wpse_lang'] );
    return false;
}
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'wpse_user_language_save' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'wpse_user_language_save' );
```

Here's an example output:

[image: wpse_lang selection]

Hopefully you can adjust this to your needs. It would be a good idea to wrap this in a class, where we could initialize it with a custom setup and re-use things for better performance. We might also consider removing the `is_admin()` check to apply this also on the front-end, but then we might need an extra `is_user_logged_in()` check.

Comment: That's amazing, thank you! Also thanks for the explanation.

Comment: You're welcome, I hope you can adjust this to your needs. I added a check so this would only be applied for non-admins (to avoid overriding the *site language* option on the `options-general.php` and `options.php` pages). @OrinLarrey